# Как лучше отображать динамические элементы?

Tags: android

В приложении грузится картинка или много картинок и под ней текстовые данные по каждой картинке. Все элементы добавляю в LinearLayout через addView циклом.
Как бы меня все устраивает, все работает так как нужно. Но вопрос, правильно ли это?
Может, правильней создать layout-файл и через адаптер подгружать туда данные. 
Подскажите правильность реализации данной функции?

**Обновление**

Чутка не доганяю, как сделать.

Есть

```
public String getItem(int i) {
        return myDate[i][i]; 
    }
```

Ну ясно, что она вернет.
И есть сам вывод в элементы:

```
viewHolder.txtItem.setText(getItem(position));
new DonloadImagTask(viewHolder.imgVItem).execute("http://xxxxxx.ru//xxx/"+getItem(position));
```

В массиве есть и путь к картинке, и дополнительная инфа. Ёе нужно вывести, но через getItem не соображу, как вывести и то, и то.
Сейчас делаю так:

```
viewHolder.txtItem.setText(mDate[position][1]);
new DonloadImagTask(viewHolder.imgVItem).execute("http://xxxxxx.ru//xxx/"+getItem(position));
```

Как правильней и лучше?

Comment: чутка не доганяю как сделать.
есть 
public String getItem(int i) {
  return myDate[i][i]; 
 }
ну ясно что она вернет.
и есть сам вывод в элементы

viewHolder.txtItem.setText(getItem(position));
new DonloadImagTask(viewHolder.imgVItem).execute("http://xxxxxx.ru//xxx/"+getItem(position));

В массисе есть и путь к картинке и дополнительная инфа. Ёе нужно вывести. но через getItem не соображу как вывести и то и то.
щас делаю так 

viewHolder.txtItem.setText(mDate[position][1]);
new DonloadImagTask(viewHolder.imgVItem).execute("http://xxxxxx.ru//xxx/"+getItem(position));

как правильней и лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: загружать такие элементы в `ListView` и использовать `ViewHolder` паттерн, который позволяет переиспользовать строки.

Comment: к примеру, вот так 
http://androiddocs.ru/pattern-viewholder-v-realizacii-spiska-listview/

Comment: тогда уж лучше переходить сразу на recyclerview